# List a saved ssh fingerprint

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, security, key-authentication

In an `ssh` client (Ubuntu 14.04), with

```
ssh-keygen -F <host>
```

some informations about `<host>` are printed, with the ECDSA key (in base64 format).

Is it possible to see its fingerprint in its original form, like when connecting to that `ssh` server for the first time? If yes, how?

Comment: You've got it backwards: the (SSH) fingerprint _is_ the hash of the publickey in wire format, what is stored in `known_hosts` and displayed by `ssh-keygen -F` is base64 of the actual (unhashed) publickey

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 oh, I didn't get it. Thank you!

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ssh-keygen  -l -F <host>`